# How to remove characters from a string until a special character?

Tags: python, json, regex, python-3.x

I have a string like this.

```
config =\
 {"status":"None",
 "numbers":["123", "123", "123"],
 "schedule":None,
 "data":{
        "x": "y"
        }
}
```

I would like to remove the config=\ from the string and get a result like this.

```
{"status":"None",
     "numbers":["123", "123", "123"],
     "schedule":None,
     "data":{
             "x": "y"
             }
    }
```

How can I get this using python regex? Would like to consider the multiline factor as well!!

I am using this method

```
re.sub(r'.*{"', '{"', script_config, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

But the code consider each line separately. Also I would like to remove only the

Comment: You can use re.sub

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regexp for it:

`string = string.replace('config =\\', '')`

If the first word is not specified:

`string = string[string.find('\\')+1:] if '\\' in string else string`

But if you want to use regexps:

`string = re.sub(r'^.*\\', '', string)`

Comment: i tried the first attempt. But in some cases, the config variable name can be different.I just need to trim the variable name before { in order to parse it as JSON.